# Riemann Sum, Ergodic Theorem and Strong Law of Large Number

Tags: riemann-sum, ergodic-theory

Suppose $\eta_t$ is a pathwise Riemann integrable stochastic process, with $t\in[0,1]$. Consider, for every partition $\{t_{j,n}=\frac{j}{n}|~j=0,...,n\}$ of $[0,1]$, the Riemann sum

$$
S_n=\sum_{j=0}^n\eta_{t_{j,n}}\,\varepsilon_{j,n}\frac{1}{n}
$$

where $\varepsilon_{j,n}$ is a triangular array of random variables. In the case the $\varepsilon_{j,n}$'s are iid with expected value $\mu$ it is immediate to prove that

$$
S_n\stackrel{p}{\to}\mu\,\int_0^1\eta_s\,ds
$$

Now assume that the $\varepsilon_{j,n}$ are not iid. Is it possible somehow to apply the [Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand.  Is the process $\eta_t$ independent of $\varepsilon_{j,n}$ variables?  Is the convergence of $S_n$ meant to be conditioned on $\eta_t$?  If so, what is the role of the process?  You could just assume $\eta_t$ is a fixed Riemann integrable function, couldn't you?

Comment: Yes $\eta_t$ is independent from the $\varepsilon$'s. Ok, let's consider $\eta_t$ as deterministic. The problem stays in the fact that $\varepsilon$'s are not supposed to be independent.

Comment: You will need some kind of weak form of iid, or at least some assumption about a common mean of the $\epsilon$ variables, otherwise this limit might not exist at all or could just be anything.

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for, do you know of some existing result in the literature?